# Runtime error 381 in removing an item from a listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Excel ranges. I want to add to a Listbox the items that are found in the first range but not in the second.

I made code that adds the first range to the listbox then a loop to remove the ones that are found in the second.

It gives me the error:
***"could not get the list property.Invalid property array index. vba removing an item from a listbox"***
Note the list box has two columns.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim stuN As Integer
stuN = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 14).Value
For i = 0 To stuN - 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 4, 1).Select
    stus.AddItem
    stus.List(i, 0) = ActiveCell.Value
    stus.List(i, 1) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
Next i

For j = 0 To stus.ListCount - 1
    Dim toF As Integer
    Dim cS As Integer

    toF = stus.List(j, 0)
    For i = 0 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("grpStus")) - 2
        cS = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 4, 16).Value
        If cS = toF Then
            stus.RemoveItem (j)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Next j      
End Sub
```

*stus* is the listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that the error is because of the

```
For i = 0 To lstbox.ListCount - 1
    lstbox.RemoveItem (i)
next i
```

because removing an item will change the

**ListCount**
 and the loop will go out of range